# Use a node.js puppeteer in a html code for OBS

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am making an overlay for OBS using HTML. I am using puppeteer to scrape my rank from tracker.gg to output it to a switch that will change the image on a local HTML page accordingly. This is my first code ever and I am not really familiar with it yet.
So far, I've made the "index.js" to scrape and set a variable for the rank

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    
    await page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()')

    const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()')
    
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent')
    const rank = await txt.jsonValue()

    var requestrank = rank.substring(15, 19)

    console.log(requestrank)

    await browser.close()
}

scrapeProduct('https://tracker.gg/valorant/profile/riot/"user"/overview')
```

And I want to link the variable from the "index.js" node to my HTML code so it can change the switch accordingly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">                         
            function request() {

                var image = document.getElementById("RankImg")                                                                 ///switch start

                var requestrank = "Diam"                                                                                       ///test the var

                switch (requestrank) {
                    case "Iron":
                        image.src = 'Images/Iron.png' ;
                        break;
                    case "Bron":
                        image.src = 'Images/Bronze.png' ;
                        break;
                    case "Silv":
                        image.src = 'Images/Silver.png' ;
                        break;
                    case "Gold":
                        image.src = 'Images/Gold.png' ;
                        break;
                    case "Plat":
                        image.src = 'Images/Platinum.png' ;
                        break;
                    case "Diam":
                        image.src = 'Images/Diamond.png' ;
                        break;
                    case "Immo":
                        image.src = 'Images/Immortal.png' ;
                        break;
                    case "Radi":
                        image.src = 'Images/Radiant.png' ;
                        break;
                    default:
                        image.src = 'Images/Base.png' ;
                }
            }                                                                                       
        </script>                                           
    </head>
    <body>

        <img src="Images/Base.png" alt="Valorant Rank" id="RankImg" onload="request()">
    
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems like if I just put in the code from "index.js" inside a script in the HTML file, it doesn't work since I am using puppeteer, so basically trying to open a browser from a browser (or so I've heard).

Comment: Your puppeter code is a nodejs(server side), that is why dont works on your browser. Is not an option for you, to run the nodejs code?

Comment: How would one do that ? The only thing I've found that worked so far was using puppeteer and a node.js. Is there any way to scrape a website without using a node and use its data for HTML javascript ?

Comment: If you want to scrap some remote website, is because you need to get some data and persist it.  Commonly you need to code that in some server side language and the run it in the server or your laptop.  The other way could be more manually: open the web in your favourite browser, open the console developer and paste some JavaScript algorithm to get some data in a popup or send it to a remote service using ajax. What do you need?

Comment: Since it is utlimately to use it as widget on obs, I think the server approach would be tedious since I don't want to have to start a server everytime I launch OBS. As I said, I am new to coding and the easy approch from internet tutorials seemed to be with a node.js, although I didn't know I had to use it on the serverside. Basically, I would like to Launch OBS, get the html page as a widget, it reloads maybe every 10-15 minutes, checks the website for the information, outputs the rank so I can use it in the switch to change the image.

Comment: A much more dumb way would be to push the result to a `.json` file then simply read that json on our `index.html` file. You don't need a server for something like this.

Comment: could you provide me with more information on how to do that ?

Comment: #1 what is obs? How do you plan to run your script every 15 minutes? Some human(you) will run it every 15 minutes in your laptop? #2 @amarinediary How do you plan to get the data from remote website to a json file without a programming language?

Comment: OBS is a streaming software that allows you to use HTML files as a source to get it as an image on the stream. Ideally, the rank checking (webscraping + image change) would be done on page reload and that can be done through OBS (basically setting it to reload the page itself) and I wouldn't have to run an external server or program besides the HTML source that is used as an input in OBS.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works

So I first generate a text file with the node.js

```
fs.writeFile("/Bibliothèques/Pictures/Graphism/New twitch gold/Widgets/Rank checker/rank.txt", requestrank, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log("The rank file was saved")
})

console.log(requestrank)
```

And then proceed to read the text file generated in the changing image function to attribute to the switch

```
async function request() {

    var image = document.getElementById("RankImg") ///set img var

    const response = await fetch('rank.txt') ///get text
    const text = await response.text()

        .then(requestrank => {
            console.log(requestrank)
            switch (requestrank) { ///switch start
                case "Iron":
                    image.src = 'Images/Iron.png';
                    break;
                case "Bron":
                    image.src = 'Images/Bronze.png';
                    break;
                case "Silv":
                    image.src = 'Images/Silver.png';
                    break;
                case "Gold":
                    image.src = 'Images/Gold.png';
                    break;
                case "Plat":
                    image.src = 'Images/Platinum.png';
                    break;
                case "Diam":
                    image.src = 'Images/Diamond.png';
                    break;
                case "Immo":
                    image.src = 'Images/Immortal.png';
                    break;
                case "Radi":
                    image.src = 'Images/Radiant.png';
                    break;
                default:
                    image.src = 'Images/Base.png';
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
} ///Twitch.tv/QuentinCly
```